# I want to get details of task manger users tab about ram and cpu utilization

Tags: powershell

I have following script, i want to get each users details of ram and cpu utilization separately in csv file. but from this script i am getting all users details in a single line instead of individually user based resources utilization details in csv file.
This is my Powershell code

```
GC c:\List.txt | % {

$xl = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false #for debugging, no prompts to save, etc.
$ConvertToGB = (1024 * 1024 * 1024)

$wkbk = $xl.Workbooks.Add()
$sheet = $wkbk.WorkSheets.Item(1)
$sheet.Name = "Transposed"
$Comp = $_
If (Test-Connection $Comp -Quiet) {
    $Luser = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_process -Filter "Name='Explorer.exe'" -ComputerName $Comp |
            % {$_.GetOwner().User} | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ","
    $Mem = GWMI -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $COMP
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Server         = $Comp
        "CPU_Usage"    = "$((GWMI -ComputerName $COMP win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average)"
        "Memory_Usage" = "$("{0:N2}" -f ((($Mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $Mem.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $Mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize)) %"
        "DiskSpace"    = "$("{0:N2}" -f (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $COMP -Filter "DriveType = 3"| Select-Object "Size","FreeSpace"))"
        #$Comp = ($disk.Size / $ConvertToGB),($disk.FreeSpace / $ConvertToGB)
        "logged_Users" = $Luser
    }
}
Else {

}
$results = Get-Service -Name *bits*| Select Server    #,"CPU usage","Memory usage","DiskFreeSpace","logged Users" 

$column = 1
$row = 1
foreach ($psRow in $results) {
    foreach ($item in $psRow.PSObject.Properties) {
        $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $column) = $item.Name
        $column++
        #$sheet.Cells.Item($row, $column) = $item."CPU","Memory_Usage","DiskSpace","logged_Users"
        $row++
        $column--
    }

} }

$obj =New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Server         = $Comp
    "CPU_Usage"    = "$((GWMI -ComputerName $COMP win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average).Average)"
    "Memory_Usage" = "$("{0:N2}" -f ((($Mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $Mem.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $Mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize)) %"
    "DiskSpace"    = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $COMP -Filter "DriveType = 3"| Select-Object "Size","FreeSpace"
    #$Comp = ($disk.Size / $ConvertToGB),($disk.FreeSpace / $ConvertToGB)
    "logged_Users" = $Luser
}
Write-Output "DiskSpace, $($obj.DiskSpace.Size), $($obj.DiskSpace.FreeSpace)"
Write-Output "Server, $($obj.Server)"
Write-Output "Memory_Usage, $($obj.Memory_Usage)"
Write-Output "logged_Users, $($obj.logged_Users)"
Write-Output "CPU_Usage, $($obj.CPU_Usage)"
$obj | ConvertTo-Csv
```

These are the results i am getting

```
Memory_Usage : 91.90 %
CPU_Usage    : 99
Server       : 127.0.0.1
logged_Users : user1,user2,user3,userA
DiskSpace    : {@{Size=718642417664; FreeSpace=317923561472}, @{Size=214747312128; FreeSpace=182724562944}, @{Size=26507997184; FreeSpace=3710320640}, 
               @{Size=1099511627776; FreeSpace=989560467456}}
```

I need this type of result in csv

```
logged users | Memory Usage in MB |  CPU Usage % | 
User1           25300                 8             
User2           33658                 15
User3           48793                 7
UserA           23564                 5
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use select-object? I can't test it b/c your script doesn't have the full code for me to test it, but it would be a little something like:

```
get-psdrive | Where Free* | Select-Object Name, @{Name='UsedGB'; Expression={$_.Used/1GB}}, @{Name='FreePerc'; Expression={'{0:p0}' -f((($_.Used)/1GB) / (($_.Free + $_.Used)/1GB))}}, @{Name='TotalSize'; Expression={($_.Free + $_.Used)/1GB}}
```

Result:

```
Name           UsedGB FreePerc        TotalSize
----           ------ --------        ---------
A    192.771030426025 81%      238.473628997803
C    336.458614349365 36%      930.742183685303
D     7043.1279296875 95%         7452.00390625
E    110.902645111084 47%      238.473628997803
```

You can use this to build the table you want.

From there, to export it to csv; I would assume you can export it with a pipe follow by export-csv -path (Destination + file name) -NoTypeInformation

Comment: -KojTug thanks for your reply, extremely sorry for incomplete code, i have updated my question regarding code, please see. By ur suggested code i can see my computer drives but this is not my requirement actually i want record ram and processor usage of each users. On my server  multiple users are logged in, and i want to record all users usage, for instance user A is using 2 gb ram and 5% processor of the server and user B is using 4 gb ram and 10% of processor and so on...

Comment: -KojTug please share your input

Comment: What’s inside that .txt file that you import?